# VM clients can not access WAN

Tags: vmware, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a new VM host on my network, on a Dell R620.

- The dedicated iDrac is connected with static IP of: 192.168.3.x
- NIC #1 is connected to my router
- The eSXI 5.1 host is with IP of 192.168.3.250
- The vSphere appliance has a static IP of 192.168.3.241
- All the clients on the new host are in the same network 192.168.3.x
- All clients are Windows 2008 R2

My problem is that non of the clients can access the WAN.

- I can't ping anything which is beyond my router.
- I CAN ping anything within my router, even if it's on a different subnet - 192.168.0.x  (Router rules are in tact and working)
- I can ping the gateway (192.168.3.254)

One thing that I checked, and is bothering my (but don't know if it has any relevance) is that on the Host Networking properties, there is a vmnic0 (picture) that shows as if it only recognizes 192.168.0.x network - is that so?

[image: vmNIC 0 on the host]

The command: `route print` shows me the following details, where I have a duplicate entry for 0.0.0.0 (and one is wrong) - which is probably also why it's not working

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check DNS, it is not configured, I think.